# QGIS Atlas Python script produces corrupt PDFs because it crashes mid export

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

My Python script freezes in the middle of execution when trying to export a `QGIS` layer as a PDF with a page per feature. It gets to the following line, and then the script simply crashes:

`result = exporter.exportToPdf(atlas, os.path.join(arbeidsmappe_path, output_pdf), QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())`.

I have a try, except block after this, which it never gets to.

Here is the full code block. I have changed some variable names to be more generic. Also some variables like directory and `arbeidsmappe_path`, it is being passed from another script.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import sys
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.core import (
    QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsPrintLayout, QgsLayoutExporter,
    QgsReadWriteContext
)

# Check for command line arguments for paths
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    directory = sys.argv[1]
    arbeidsmappe_path = sys.argv[2]
else:
    print("Directory and arbeidsmappe path were not provided.")
    sys.exit(1)

# Set up the QGIS application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.30.3\bin", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Function to generate atlas from a .qpt file
def generate_atlas_from_template(qpt_file, output_pdf, layout_name):
    print(f"Starting to generate atlas from template: {qpt_file}", flush=True)
    # Load the project file
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    if not project.read(os.path.join(directory, 'Presentasjon_analyse_NIS-FKB_test.qgs')):
        print(f"Failed to read the project file: {os.path.join(directory, 'Presentasjon_analyse_NIS-FKB_test.qgs')}", flush=True)
        return
    
    project.read(os.path.join(directory, 'Presentasjon_analyse_NIS-FKB_test.qgs'))
    print("Project file loaded successfully", flush=True)

    # Read in the .qpt file
    template_path = os.path.join(directory, qpt_file)
    try:
        with open(template_path) as f:
            template_content = f.read()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to read the template file: {template_path}. Error: {e}", flush=True)
        return
    
    print("Template file read successfully", flush=True)
    template_content = open(template_path).read()
    document = QDomDocument()
    document.setContent(template_content)

    # Create a new layout
    layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
    layout.initializeDefaults()
    if not layout.loadFromTemplate(document, QgsReadWriteContext()):
        print(f"Failed to load layout from the template", flush=True)
        return
    
    print("Layout loaded from template successfully", flush=True)
    layout.loadFromTemplate(document, QgsReadWriteContext())

    # Assume layout and atlas are already configured in the .qpt file
    atlas = layout.atlas()
    atlas.setEnabled(True)  # Just ensure atlas is enabled, in case it's not set in the template

    # Proceed to export the atlas to a PDF  
    exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
    print(arbeidsmappe_path)
    try:
        print(f"Exporting atlas to {output_pdf}...", flush=True)
        result = exporter.exportToPdf(atlas, os.path.join(arbeidsmappe_path, output_pdf), QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())

        if result != QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
            print(f"Failed to export atlas for {output_pdf}")
        else:
            print(f"Atlas successfully exported to {output_pdf}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while exporting atlas for {output_pdf}: {e}")


# Generate atlas for each template
generate_atlas_from_template(r'C:\\Atlas_template\template1.qpt', '1.pdf', '1_layout')
generate_atlas_from_template(r'C:\Atlas_template\template2.qpt', '2.pdf', '2_layout')
generate_atlas_from_template(r'C:\Atlas_template\template3', '3.pdf', '3_layout')

# Clean up the QGIS application
qgs.exitQgis()
```

The script is supposed to create one `PDF` consisting of multiple pages per data layer in my `.QGS` project file, but it simply crashes out during the first layer it gets to.

EDIT: I ended up abandoning the idea to use atlas outside of QGIS and instead used PyQGIS which I turned into a plugin. I'll share the code with anyone if they're curious.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @СергейКох The problem is that the code fails to output a working PDF. It gets stuck on exporter.exportToPdf and then simply freezes or times out. I have tried to implement some logging in form of the print statements in the try/except block, but it never reaches it. It produces a PDF but it is corrupted and fails to open (and is probably one tenth the file size it should be).

Comment: There is no `for` loop that goes through the layers and for each a page is created, that would also explain the reduced file size.